# How to Create a dropdown Button with see more option and on click toggle should not happen in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want to add see more option to fetch data

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={(e) => {this.showAllData(e)} }>See Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I Just want to fetch more data on click of dropdown item without closing dropdown, can anyone give to solution to figure out this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just keep **toggle={false}** for **dropdown item**

```
<DropdownItem toggle={false} onClick={(e) => {this.showAllData(e)} }>See Action</DropdownItem>
```